# Route to AngularJS Page with :id parameter

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have an AngularJS Application which uses `ngRoute` to handle the routing of the app. The routing itself is working (the URL is being redirected to the correct page and the correct partial is open) however, I cannot retrieve the item which I need in the second page.

The first page lets you search for a list of documents (dummy at the moment but will eventually link to an API). The list items are clickable and will route you to the second page where the details of the document are listed.

I will outline the way I am attempting to achieve this at the moment but I am open to suggestions if anyone has ideas about how this solution can be improved.

**`app.js`**

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate"])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/main", {
            templateUrl: "Views/main.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        })
        .when("/document/:id", {
            templateUrl: "Views/document.html",
            controller: "DocumentController"
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: "/main"});
});
```

**`main.html`**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/main.css" type="text/css">

<div id="docSearchPanel" class="col-xs-12">
    <ng-include src="'Views/Partials/documentSearchForm.html'"></ng-include>
</div>

<div id="formSearchResultsArea">
        <div id="documentsFoundHeader">Documents Found</div>
    <div id="documentsTableContainer">
        <table id="documentsTable" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="doc in documents" ng-click="showDocument()">
                    <td>{{doc.documentID}}</td>
                    <td>{{doc.documentTitle}}</td>
                    <td>{{doc.documentStatus}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

**`main.ctrl.js`**

```
angular.module("app").controller("MainController", function($scope, $location){

    //This is populated by a function I have removed to keep the code simple
    $scope.documents = []           

    $scope.showDocument = function(){
        $scope.activeDocument = this.doc;
        $location.path("document/"+this.doc.documentID);
    };
});
```

**`document.html`**

```
<form ng-submit="downloadForm()" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <h2>Document Details</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <h3>{{activeDocument.documentTitle}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="field in selected.fields">  
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="document-attribute-header col-xs-5">{{field.key}}</div>
            <div class="document-attribute-value col-xs-7">{{field.val}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**`document.ctrl.js`**

```
angular.module("app").controller("DocumentController", function($scope, $location, $routeParams){
    $scope.activeDocument = getActiveDocument($routeParams.id);

    function getActiveDocument(id){
        for (var d in $scope.documents){
            var doc = $scope.documents[d];
            if (doc.documentID == id)
                return doc;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $scope-objects in the two controllers are not the same. You either make "documents" a member of the $rootScope (which you would need to inject in both controllers) or you make a documents-service which you inject.
Hope, that helped.

Comment: Thanks that did help. :)